# Getting React flow error: module is not a polymorphic type. How to extend a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, javascript-inheritance

I am trying to extend my existing layout to basically override the method renderHeader() but flow doesn't like it:

> module ./Layout [1] is not a polymorphic type.

how do I fix this?

here is a class I am trying to extend (it's not abstract):
**Layout.js**

```
//@flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Header from '../header/Header';
import '../../css/settings/utilities.css';

export type LayoutProps = {
    children: React.Node,
};

class Layout extends React.PureComponent<LayoutProps> {
    renderHeader() {
        return <Header />;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1 className="u-hd">My Wee Loyalty Prime</h1>
                {this.renderHeader()}
                <main className="main">{this.props.children}</main>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Layout;
```

here is my class which should extend:
**LayoutRegistration.js**

```
//@flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Header from '../header/Header';
import * as Layout from './Layout';
import '../../css/settings/utilities.css';

export default class LayoutRegistration extends Layout {
    renderHeader() {
        return <Header showSubnav={false} />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
import * as Layout from './Layout';
```

results in `Layout` import being module object, while it's expected to be a class.

Since `Layout` component is default export, it should be:

```
import Layout from './Layout';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//@flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Header from '../header/Header';
import '../../css/settings/utilities.css';
//Change te type to interface. Since type is not assignable to interface
type LayoutProps<T> {
    children: React.Node
};

class Layout<T> extends React.PureComponent<*, LayoutProps<T>, *> {
    renderHeader() {
        return <Header />;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1 className="u-hd">My Wee Loyalty Prime</h1>
                {this.renderHeader()}
                <main className="main">{this.props.children}</main>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: exchanging type with interface doesn't fix the error. is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: import Layout from './Layout'; fixed the issue